# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.a.a.k.f(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, android

I ahve some apps with tasget sdk version 18 (android 4.3). I have 4.3 SDK installed in eclipse. And it works fine on my Nexus 4 with custom 4.3 rom. But when I try to install it on my Nexus 4 with custom 4.4 rom, I get force close with this erron in my google play console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.a.a.k.f(Unknown Source)
at com.a.a.d.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I have some intro screen with Enter button to go to my main activity. When I click this button I get this force close. IS this because of the 4.4 rom, and my 4.3 target sdk version?

Comment: This code looks obfuscated. Turn off proguard and try again.

Comment: I don't use proguard.

Comment: Verify that you aren't using proguard and try it on a stock rom/emulator. If it works fine on stock, then your custom rom might be the cause.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. So you don't think it has something to do with target sdk version?